# How to view the sent headers with mitmproxy

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm doing some work with mitmproxy and was wondering how can I get the headers and data that is passed via GET/POST commands. For example I see the following outputted from mitmproxy:

```
IPADDRESS GET http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/9418ASD23801.jpg
```

But I would want to see all of the data that is being passed included user agents, headers, etc. The same goes for post examples.

Comment: If you're using mitmproxy, you can just press enter to view the flow with headers and content. If you're using mitmdump, you can supply `-d` to get the headers printed, `-dd` for more details. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

For new version of mitmproxy `--flow-detail 2` can be used, example with docker:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 mitmproxy/mitmproxy mitmdump --flow-detail 2
```